# How to filter android HCI snoop of a single application

Tags: android, bluetooth, btsnoop

I'm testing an application on my android phone and I'm trying to analyze its BLE communications.
I tried to run the application, perform my test, close it and retrieve btsnoop_hci from `adb bugreport` and everything works. The difficulty I'm facing is that the file I get contains every Bluetooth communication of the phone and not the one I'm interested in, so trying to understand what are the messages I'm interested in is pretty difficult.
Is there a way to filter the messages of the tested application using wireshark or similar programs? If not, is there a way (during the test) to shut all communications apart from the app I'm testing?